# How to download a file from Firebase RealtimeDatabase that is saved in the FirebaseStorage using the file location link?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm making an Online Learning Management System app. I have created a table for Lessons and the lecture slides are there in that table. Admin can upload the lecture slides to the database and users should be able to download them through the LessonsActivity. When the admin uploads a lecture slide, the file is being saved on the FirebaseStorage and the file location (file path) is being saved in the Lessons table in the Database. I want to let the user go into whatever Subject they like, and download the lessons using the Button that I have assigned in the layout file of that Activity (Using the file paths that is saved in the database. **Not using the FirebaseStorage Reference**).

I watched a video and tried to use the DownloadManager feature but it showed only to download files straight from the FirebaseStorage.

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Lessons> options =
            new  FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Lessons>()
                    .setQuery(LessonsRef.orderByChild("subject_id").equalTo(subject_id), Lessons.class)
                    .build();

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Lessons, LessonsViewHolder> adapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Lessons, LessonsViewHolder>(options) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LessonsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final Lessons model)
                {

                        holder.lname.setText(model.getName());
                        downloadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                //download();
                            }

                        });

                }


                @NonNull
                @Override
                public LessonsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
                {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lessons_layout, parent, false);
                    LessonsViewHolder holder = new LessonsViewHolder(view);
                    return holder;
                }
            };

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.startListening();
    GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(LessonsActivity.this, 1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
}
```

Here is my [Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTg9R.png).

[image]

Comment: What's the problem you have when you  download the files as explained here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files?

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    final File localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
    storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.getAbsolutePath());
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e ) {}
```